# send dynamic table via email

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on this web application that needs to send a certain report. The report is dynamic however and it is in a table format. The thing i hope to do now is to email the whole table via email to someone. Is there any way I can do so?

php script

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con) 
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
    $input = $_POST['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '$input'");

    echo "<table border='5' align=center>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Setting</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Actual</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        { 
         echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Setting'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Value'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Actual'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 

            if($row['Value'] != $row['Actual']) 
                { 
                echo "<td bgcolor='#FD2911'>" . "X" . "</td>";
                } 
            else 
                { 
                echo "<td bgcolor='#1CDC15'>" . "O" . "</td>";
                } 
        }
    echo "<br>";

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

html code

```
    <form action="query1.php" method="POST">
    Enter the choice: <input type="varchar" name="id" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Audit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You don't want to `echo` the table, you want to append it to a string, and send the string using PHP's `mail()`. However, if you are able to use a framework such as [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), this will be much simpler.

Comment: thank you! i will try doing your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You concatenate the whole table:

```
$table = '';
$table .= "<table border='5' align=center>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Setting</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Actual</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    { 
     $table .= "<tr>";
  $table .= "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  $table .= "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
  $table .= "<td>" . $row['Setting'] . "</td>";
  $table .= "<td>" . $row['Value'] . "</td>";
  $table .= "<td>" . $row['Actual'] . "</td>";
  $table .= "</tr>"; 

        if($row['Value'] != $row['Actual']) 
            { 
            $table .= "<td bgcolor='#FD2911'>" . "X" . "</td>";
            } 
        else 
            { 
            $table .= "<td bgcolor='#1CDC15'>" . "O" . "</td>";
            } 
    }
$table .= "</table><br>";

mail('to@example.com', 'My Subject', $table);
```

Comment: hey thank you for the reply. but i have tried that before and it returns a warning now. Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dynamicemail1.php on line 39. 

and i tried sending it over to my email and i did not receive anything

Comment: Did you copy pasted the code? You didn't add the database connection?

Comment: well the db connection is in my code actually. mm, do you need it?

Comment: the page has to display correctly before you can mail the table

Comment: no, I don't need it, make sure first you get some code from your database then try to send by email.

Comment: forgot to close the </table> tag after the while statement Mihai

Comment: oh i already closed it. however the code doesnt seem to work after I concatenated the table

Answer (score 0):

if you are wanting to do more than the table, you could use output buffering;

```
<?php
ob_start();

# all your code/page/table(s) with echos and all

$toBeSent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

then send the entire contents between ob_start and ob_end_clean via email by replacing $table in the mail() line of Mihai's post with $toBeSent.

Comment: to be clear, output buffering, and subsequently capturing and emailing the buffer, will only work if the page is already functional and displaying the table/page as you intended.  Sounds like you have some database retrieval issues in the other response.

Comment: nah. it worked fine. which is why i decided to add in the email function. think the problem lies after concatenating

Comment: so if you add `echo $table;` it shows the table on the page?

I recommend splitting the problem into its componants; (1) do you have a table that is formatted correctly - tested by output of the resulting concatenation to the screen, and (2) testing that email functionality works - tested with a simple `mail('you@yourdomain.ext','test subject','hello world');`